# Configure Wireless Router to also distribute IPTV

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I use both IPTV and ADSL internet services from the same provider. The provider uses VPI 0 and VCI 35 for the IPTV service and VPI 0 and VCI 33 for the Internet. There is a building near where i want to have both IPTV and Internet. The modem is in another building and i cannot move it.

Is it possible to set one port on the modem as bridge and trace a ethernet cable to the other building, where it will be plugged into an wireless router which will use virtual circuits to both offer wired IPTV and wifi internet?